# is there a way to add 2 yticks and 2 bars in one matplotlib plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Hello i want to ask if there is a way to add another yticks with bars in the same plot?

This would be an example:
[image: https://image.ibb.co/jXSugF/Untitled.jpg]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please consider adding a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get useful answers on this site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible way, using `ax.set_yticklabels`:

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)

x = np.arange(8)
y1 = np.random.rand(4)
y2 = np.random.rand(4)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.barh(x[::2], y1, color="C3")
ax.barh(x[1::2], y2, color="C0")

t = range(len(x))
ax.set_yticks(t)
t[0::2] = ["another tick"]*(len(x)/2)
t[1::2] = ["tick {}".format(i+1) for i in range((len(x)/2))]
ax.set_yticklabels(t)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```